# Connections issues SQLPLUS to Oracle 11g Database using Windows 10

Tags: windows, oracle, oracle11g, sqlplus

11g XE Version 11.2.0
instance name is xe

Path to SQLPLUS.exe

> G:\JaveWebApps\Oracle11gDb\app\oracle\product\11.2.0\server\bin

When I try to run sqlplus in cmd in C:\Users\User> I keep getting this error:

SP2-0750: You may need to set ORACLE_HOME to your Oracle software directory.

Here are my ENVIRONMENT VARS

> ORACLE HOME
>
> G:\JaveWebApps\Oracle11gDb\app\oracle\product\11.2.0\server

Path

> %ORACLE_HOME%\bin;C:\Python34\Lib\site-packages\PyQt4;C:\Python34\;C:\Python34\Scripts;%SystemRoot%\system32;%SystemRoot%;%SystemRoot%\System32\Wbem;%SYSTEMROOT%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;G:\XAMPP\php;C:\ProgramData\ComposerSetup\bin;%USERPROFILE%.dnx\bin;C:\Program Files\Microsoft DNX\Dnvm\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Windows Performance Toolkit\;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_45\bin

These are the commands I ran in this order

> echo %ORACLE_HOME%
>
> G:\JaveWebApps\Oracle11gDb\app\oracle\product\11.2.0\server
>
> set ORACLE_SID =  xe
>
> set ORACLE_HOME = G:\JaveWebApps\Oracle11gDb\app\oracle\product\11.2.0\server
>
> sqlplus

ERROR 6 initializing SQLPLUS

You may beed to set ORACLE_HOME to your Oracle software directory.

There are multiple cases online with the same error, but none of them are working for me.

Comment: I think it should be:  G:\JaveWebApps\Oracle11gDb\app\oracle\product\11.2.0

Comment: Hm, I tried that as well with no luck. Per, another answer that was marked correct on stackoverflow. It should be exactly as I have it.